# Can I have someone else submit my title paperwork for a car?

Tags: vehicle, title

A few months back I decided to buy out a vehicle that I had a lease for.

I sent a check to the finance company managing the lease, and after many shenanigans, 2.5 months later I received their title in the mail with the assignment to me.

After I had purchased the car from them, late april or so, when I got confirmation that the lease was paid off, I took the car to a dealership from the same manufacturer and 'sold' them the car.

Only, they did not pay me for the car. I gave them the car and we filled out the paperwork, but they said they couldn't pay me until I get the title from the leasing company and am able to sign it.

Months later, I now finally have the title. However, it's in the leasing company's name and is 'assigned' to me on the back... And my understanding is that I need to go to the DMV, get a new title in **MY** name, and then I can sign it over to the dealership.

The problem is, the reason I was selling the car in the first place is that **I moved to, and still live in, Mexico.**

The DMV's around where this dealership is - Humble, TX, near Houston - are all appointment-only, and are booked up through next week.

I **flew in** to pick up this title that was mailed out to a PO box of mine from the leasing company, and won't be here long enough to get an appointment at the DMV to get a copy of the title in my name.

My question(s) is/are...

- Can I give the dealership I sold the car to, the existing copy of the title that just has me listed on the 'assigned to' section, and can they handle it from there? I'm assuming no
- Is there any way I can authorize someone else to go handle the title transfer paperwork for me? Is there perhaps a service anyone knows of that can do this?
- If neither of the above... Am I stuck just flying back here again, internationally, when I can get a DMV appointment?

Comment: Have you asked the dealer?

Comment: I haven't asked the dealer yet, I just realized this issue overnight and I am only in town until 11:30am-12pm today. I am going to try and go to the DMV in person and see if I can get away with a walk-in when they've so clearly said appointment only... then i'm going to go to the dealer and hope there's something they can do. Then I'm back off to the airport back to mexico  I'm concerned I spent a few hundred dollars on this trip just to pick up a piece of mail and will be repeating it again just to handle the DMV bit later on